# Docker run - format issue - docker: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, influxdb, docker-machine

I hope this msg finds you well and healthy,

Im trying to run the commands bellow on Redhat 8

Docker version 20.10.3, build 48d30b5

and getting the error bellow, I'm not a Docker expert so not sure how to solve it, I appreciate your help,

```
docker run --rm \
  -e INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
  -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin \ -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secretpassss \
  -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassss1 \
  -v influxdb-volume:/var/lib/influxdb \
  influxdb /init-influxdb.sh
```

Once copy past in terminal, Im getting an error

```
  [root@dca monitoring]# 
  [root@dca monitoring]# docker run --rm \
>    -e INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true \
>    -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin \ -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secretpassss \
>    -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassss1 \
>    -v influxdb-volume:/var/lib/influxdb \
>    influxdb /init-influxdb.sh 
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
[root@dca monitoring]#
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but providing a tag with the image works, try this:
`docker run --rm -e INFLUXDB_DB=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_ENABLED=true -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=admin -e INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secretpassss -e INFLUXDB_USER=telegraf -e INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD=secretpassss1 -v influxdb-volume:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb:latest /init-influxdb.sh`, looks like the image is considered as an option to the `-v` flag and not the image itself.

Comment: There's a lot of extra backslashes; backslash-space `\ ` in the middle of a line will introduce a space character, which will be interpreted as part of the `docker run` command, which will be taken as the image name.  The only backslashes should be at the very end of lines and there can be absolutely nothing after them, only a newline.

Comment: Thank you guys :D